# Copy files which matches requirement to the new folder

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I have original folder with 2000 files (`patha`), now I want to copy only the file which match my requirement (list in `grdc_no`) to new path (`pathb`). Here is my performance:

```
grdc_no <- grdc$grdc_no       
# list of file name satisfied with my requirement

all_files <- list.files("patha", full.names = TRUE)

for (f in all_files) {

  for (i in 1:length(grdc_no)) {

    if (f == grdc_no[i]) {
      file.copy(f, "pathb")
    } else {}
  }
}
```

However, it does not work. Any advice for me in this case? Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this without a loop (and especially a nested one) using `lapply`:

`lapply(all_files[basename(all_files) %in% grdc_no],function(x) file.copy(x,"pathb"))`

This will index files from `all_files` with a matching filename in the vector `grdc_no` and apply `file.copy` to it.

Comment: Wow, exact what I want. Your help is truly worth to me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy it helped, kindly consider accepting it as solution.